# How to publish TypeScript modules on NPM without "dist" in import?

Tags: angular, typescript, npm

I'm trying to publish a typescript library on NPM but I can't to have a "good" path after publishing.

I follow several guide on this point but I'm not found a solution.

The problem: So, consider the following structure:

```
dist
 |- Alls files generated after tsc build
lib
 |- All TS files of library (source)
CHANGELOG.md
LICENSE
package.json
README.md
tsconfig.json
```

After publishing, for instance in an Angular application, I shall type:

```
import {Component} from '<library name>/dist/Component';
```

My question: How can I configure project import to have `from '<library name>/Component'` instead `from '<library name>/dist/Component'` please?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On suggestions of @joe-clay, I found a solution.

My new structure is the following:

```
dist
 |- Alls files generated after tsc build
 |- package.json
 |- LICENSE
 |- README.md
src
 |- All TS files of library (source)
CHANGELOG.md
LICENSE
README.md
tsconfig.json
```

The `dist` directory is published on NPM with README.md and LICENSE file for NPM package page.

The root directory is the entry point on Github with README.md, LICENSE and CHANGELOG.md for development process on Github.

`tsconfig.json` is placed on the root because I don't find a solution to have correct build if located inside `dist` directory.

In `package.json`, I add the script `"build": "cd ../ && tsc"` in order to be able to execute `npm run build` inside `dist` directory.

With this structure, library development and NPM publishing works fine.

And I can use this import from my application:

```
import {Component} from '<library name>/Component';
```

Thank you again.

Answer (score 9):

I found a pretty clean solution that doesn't require copying your package.json into your dist or publishing from dist.

You can structure your project as:

```
package.json (for entire project)
src
 | secondary-package-name
   |- index.ts
secondary-package-name
 |- package.json (for secondary-module-name)
dist
 |- generated files
```

the package.json for your secondary module just needs to contain

```
{
  "name": "package/secondary-package-name",
  "private": true,
  "main": "../dist/secondary-package-name/index.js"
}
```

to point back to your `dist`

You should then be able to reference exports from the secondary package like so:

```
import { someFn } from "package/secondary-package-name"
```

provided it is exported from the index.ts file in that directory

You'll also need to make sure the `files` field of your main package.json includes:

```
"files": [
    "dist",
    "secondary-package-name"
  ],
```

Comment: Thank you, very useful! This can even be automated :P

Comment: Super grateful for this, it works perfectly. The imports also work in a regular javascript project.


`const { someFn } = require('package/secondary-package-name')`

Answer (score 4):

This might be a little different than what you were looking for, but I think this is the more standard approach.  Instead of trying to import from different directories in your module, just use a single `main.ts` file to gather everything up for export.  Assuming that you have this `main.ts` file in your lib directory that re-exports everything, you can just configure the package.json to point to the generated JS.

Folder structure:

```
dist
 |- main.js
 |- main.d.ts
 |- all other generates files
lib
 |- main.ts
...
```

package.json:

```
{
    ...
    "main": "./dist/main.js",
    "types": "./dist/main.d.ts",
    ...
}
```

In this example, if you have the following in your main.ts:

```
export const testValue = 5;
```

You could import it in other code that depends on this library by using `import { testValue } from '<library>';`

Check out the [typescript docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/publishing.html) for more info about this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but my problematic is to manage several class with different "namespace". For instance, I should be able to do the following import from the library: `import {Class1} from '<library>/Class1'; import {Class2} from '<library>/SubModule/Class2';`. Any idea please? Thank you.

Comment: Don't use main.ts - instead use index.ts, and if you want "namespaces" then create a subdirectory, and inside every subdirectory you also create an index.ts (which only exports the types that you want in that "namespace"). If you use index.ts files like this (which is standard) then it will work automatically: if you import `'<library>/SubModule'` it will allow you to import anything that you've exported in the file `'<library>/SubModule/index.ts'`

Answer (score 3):

The vast majority of module bundling tools follow [Node's module resolution rules](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_node_modules_folders), which effectively say that if you specify a path after a library name, it will resolve that relative to the module's `node_modules` folder. You can't override this, and it's [almost certainly never going to change](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/10506) for backward compatibility reasons.

Without asking for your users to configure their module bundler, the only way this can be achieved is by publishing your package with the directory structure matching that which you wish to expose to your users. You could use scripts/NPM hooks (e.g. `prepublish` and `postpublish`) to automate this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and reference links, it's clearer to me. So I look for for a solution to expose only the `dist` folder. If you know a guide for this, that's welcome. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I just found about this question. Sure enough 2018 is far away, but since then tools have evolved. I've been searching for the same clean structure, for which I have a proposed solution as a SO question (actively looking for criticism/feedbacks)

[Creating a usable library on npm... with yarn workspaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67060817/creating-a-usable-library-on-npm-with-yarn-workspaces)

Basically the idea being very similar to @clem and @wilcoxmd answers, but backed with yarn workspaces for the automation of the "upper layer".