# typescript npm package - how to not having to import from "dist/"

Tags: typescript, npm, package.json, tsconfig

I am trying to build a utility npm package. In my `src` directory I have a bunch of typescript files that declare multiple interfaces / types. For example in `src/value-updatable.ts` I have:

```js
export interface UnaryValueUpdatable<T> {
  value: T;
  onChange: (value: T) => void;
}
```

I compile my entire source to `dist/`, because it is a utility package there's **no entry or main file**, I just want to use the types in other projects. I am not even sure if compiling is necessary but the problem is still the same. When I install the package in a different project I have to import from the `dist/` or `src/` rather than from the package name itself.

**For example:**

`import {UnaryValueUpdatable} from "my-utility-package/dist/UnaryValueUpdatable"`

How do I have to configure my package to expose "pretty" paths like that: `import {whatever} from "my-utility-package/whatever"`?

**package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "my-utility-package",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "files": [
    "dist/**/*"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc"
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "typescript": "^3.6.4"
  }
}
```

**tsconfig:**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "jsx": "react"
  },
  "include": ["src"],
  "exclude": ["dist"]
}
```

Comment: dont think its possible without some build tooling to set up the published package that way, https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/10506

Comment: Thank you @WayneC. Basically every package that I know has the kind of import that i try to achieve. Which tooling is commonly used to achieve this?

Comment: @PhilipFeldmann did you solved it? I have the same problem.

Comment: @walter_dl No, unfortunately I'm still accessing it via the dist path...

Comment: You might be able to use the solution in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62482409/5574183

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to publish TypeScript modules on NPM without "dist" in import?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49858168/how-to-publish-typescript-modules-on-npm-without-dist-in-import)

Comment: Add this to your package.json: `"main": "dist/index.js"` ofc this assumes you have created a index.ts file that exports your stuff in your src root folder (or whatever folder is your src folder. You might want this too if you export typings: `"typings": "dist/index.d.ts"`. (Sorry for the short explanaition.)

Answer (score 3):

You can create directories in your project root that contain `package.jsons`s that point to the directory you want to expose in your `dist`.

You can structure your project as:

```
package.json (for entire project)
src
 | secondary-package-name
   |- index.ts
secondary-package-name
 |- package.json (for secondary-module-name)
dist
 |- generated files
```

the package.json for your secondary module just needs to contain

```
{
  "name": "package/secondary-package-name",
  "private": true,
  "main": "../dist/secondary-package-name/index.js"
}
```

to point back to your `dist`

You should then be able to reference exports from the secondary package like so:

```
import { someFn } from "package/secondary-package-name"
```

provided it is exported from the index.ts file in that directory

You'll also need to make sure the `files` field of your main package.json includes the new directory:

```
"files": [
  "dist",
  "secondary-package-name"
],
```

(originally answered in https://stackoverflow.com/a/62482409/5574183)